# NextJS app point to domain and subdomain using the same base of code

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I have a NextJS application hosted on Vercel and I want one section of the app to point to a subdomain, using the same deploy and base of code.

Let's say I have this folder structure:

```
app/
 |_ (auth)/
       |_ signin/
       |_ register/
 |_ (dashboard)/
       |_ customer/
       |_ admin/
 |_ (home)/
       |_ page.tsx
 |_ page.tsx
 |_ layout.tsx
```

What I want to achieve is to have the auth and home Route Groups to point to `mydomain.com` and the dashboard Route Groups to point to `app.mydomain.com`

I'm using the new Next13 app folder.

It's possible to achieve this behavior ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible the way you want. You should probably have two separate Next.js apps in one __monorepo__ this way, both apps can share code but they will have separate routing. On Vercel you can then create projects for both apps and assign the domains to the respective projects

Comment: I find a way of doing it. In the `middleware.ts`, using `rewrites` and `redirects` will do the work. I learned from Steven Tey's repositories, [dub](https://github.com/steven-tey/dub) and [platforms](https://github.com/vercel/platforms)